# Bootstrap and jquery not published to Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I created a sample project from template asp core web application in VS2019.
Local build works fine.
I have a repo in Bitbucket which I connected to azure app service through deployment center and I pushed sample project to that repo.
Project gets properly noticed and built. Deployment has status successful, but opening it shows that bootstrap and jquery cannot be found. Scm shows, that they were not published:
[image]

What do I have to do/set to properly set up push/build/deployment sequence?
Note: code that loads bootstrap and jquery is not conditional - it doesn't depend on environment

Comment: Can you check by publishing in a local folder (right click project -> publish -> select a folder) to see if those get published? I suspect it's something to do with your .csproj file.

Comment: Yes, there was issue with .csproj file (strange that it's in a VS template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your csproj file and verify if they are not getting excluded.
I had a similiar issue recently, I had to manually remove the excludes and added the below to my csproj file to make it work.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```